# Trying to generate proto to dart file

Tags: flutter, dart, proto

I'm trying to generated proto file to dart file with protoc-plugin follow this instruction https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/dart/ but when I run this command line

```
protoc --dart_out=grpc:lib/proto --plugin=protoc-gen-dart=C:/src/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/bin/protoc-gen-dart.bat -Iprotobuf protobuf/utils.proto
```

And it showed this error:

```
'dart' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'pub' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
--dart_out: protoc-gen-dart: Plugin failed with status code 1.
```

I have installed dart as a plugin in my Android Studio. Is that I have to install dart SDK and add it to environment variable path to work?

**Update**

It worked after i install dart sdk and restart my pc.

Answer (score 4):

Seeing the Flutter tag, I presume that Flutter SDK was what you had before you install Dart SDK as said in your update.

If you want to do this without having to install Dart SDK separately (since Flutter SDK has Dart SDK within itself already), the environment has to know where the following are at:

- Flutter SDK

  - eg: `export PATH="~/desktop/development/flutter/bin:$PATH"`
- Dart SDK within Flutter SDK

  - eg: `export PATH="~/desktop/development/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin:$PATH"`
- Pub cache within Flutter SDK (where the protoc plugin will be located at)

  - eg: `export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/desktop/development/flutter/.pub-cache/bin"`

The given examples above are from `.bash_profile` in macOS, but in essence, the environment has to know where these 3 are before trying to globally activate the plugin via `flutter pub global activate protoc_plugin` and then generate Dart code from proto files.

Answer (score 1):

The file protoc-gen-dart.bat actually has bugs in it. It's trying to run exe called `pub` which doesn't exist. You need to manually edit the file. It should be

`dart pub global run protoc_plugin:protoc_plugin %*`

not

`pub global run protoc_plugin:protoc_plugin %*`

Once I changed this, I was able to generate protos for Dart on Windows